# Ruby string prepend '\' character

Tags: ruby, string, ruby-2.0

why ruby is prepends '\' character while I am trying to run below code. It is happening with only '#$'

It is happening with all ruby version.

```
puts '#$'   => '\#$'
```

or

```
'#$'  => '\#$'
```

or

```
'mypassord#$123'  =>  'mypassord\#$123'
```

Please share you experience here. Is it a ruby problem or anything?

Comment: The output you have shown, I am not getting exactly like that.. Did you minimize something ? :-) I am getting `"\\\#$" `.

Comment: @ArupRakshit no, just open irb and type '#$'. I got this.

Comment: yes.. If I run it in IRB, i get what I shown above. But if I run it from `Vim` command prompt, I am getting `'#$'`.

Comment: Okay.. from vim now `puts '#$'.inspect` is giving exactly like yours.

Comment: I guess you are both wrong. Ruby's string inspection uses double quotes. It should be `"\#$"`, and that is crucial since single quoted string literals do not have interpolation.

Comment: @sawa Nothing wrong.. I know what you said. I am trying to get the exact output like OP. :-)

Answer (score 5):

No it is not a ruby problem. It is your problem. Since `#$foo` can be interpreted as interpolation of the global variable `$foo`, it is necessary to escape the `#` character. That is why there is a backslash.

To be more precise, there is no possibility of interpolation with the string `"#$"` (`$` is an invalid global variable) or `"#$123"` (`$123` is an invalid global variable), but it makes the inspection algorithm or the interpolation algorithm complicated to check the sequence after `#$`, so I guess that is why `#` is escaped even in such cases.

Comment: You are right. `IRB` calls `#inspect`, which makes it *double quoted string*. Rule wise, [inside double quoted string all especial characters must be **escaped**](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/doc/syntax/literals_rdoc.html#label-Strings). `#` has special meaning, inside the double quoted string, so it must be stopped using a *backslash*.

Comment: @ArupRakshit That is not quite correct. `#` is not a special character by itself (`"foo#bar"`). It is context dependent.

Comment: Yes.. That's what I meant to say.. :-) You used *correct word*.

Comment: Ruby interpolation works with double quote but I am using single quote... It should not happen with single quote.

Comment: RKP.. You used it in `IRB`, and `IRB` made it *double quoted* by calling `#inspect`.

Comment: Then What is the solution if I need exact string as I entered.

Comment: @RKP It is impossible to get that. The moment a string literal is parsed, it is interpreted as a string object, and the literal expression is thrown away. There is no way to distinguish `'foo'` from `"foo"`.